# How can I write tests for non-web code in EmberJS app?

Tags: testing, ember.js

I have ember addon, which introduces new commands.

Ember commands are not web javascript, it's Node.

I want to write tests for this logic (at least, unit), but can't find how to do it from the docs.
All testing documentation seem to be related to testing web logic

Answer (score 1):

Addons such as [ember-cli-deploy](https://github.com/ember-cli-deploy/ember-cli-deploy) have setup node tests and used a node test runner (mocha in the case of ember-cli-deploy) to run them. Because this has nothing to do with Ember.js, it's not standardized in ember-cli, however you can easily do this outside the ember-cli environment.

Here's a good primer on how to write tests in node using mocha:
https://medium.com/serverlessguru/how-to-unit-test-with-nodejs-76967019ba56